# (racket) performance of hash-set vs hash-set! and functional programming

Tags: performance, racket

I'm working on a Commodore 64 emulator as a fun project with functional programming. My goal was to write the entire thing functionally and as pure as possible. I was looking at using a hash table as my memory store, but the performance of mutable vs immutable hashes seems prohibitive. I liked the idea of a hash table as kind of sparse array of memory, since in many cases, memory won't actually be instantiated. I'd be fine using a vector as well, but there doesn't seem to be a functional version of vector-set.

```lisp
(define (immut-hash [c (hash)] [r 10000000])
  (when (> r 0) (immut-hash (hash-set c (random #xffff) (random #xff)) (- r 1))))

(define (mut-hash [c (make-hash)] [r 10000000])
  (when (> r 0) (hash-set! c (random #xffff) (random #xff)) (mut-hash c (- r 1))))
```

(time (immut-hash)) vs (time (mut-hash)) is much worse, as a simulation of a bunch of memory pokes, and puts it beyond the ability of my macbook pro to keep up with a c64 clock rate.

(a) Is there any better approach to improve the performance of the mutable hashes in this case?
(b) If not, is there another functional approach people would suggest?

Note - I know that this isn't likely the right solution for absolute performance. Like I said..learning.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old discussion, but it is the top hit for searching for the performance of Racket's hash-set (e.g. the immutable, functional way of setting a hash key value pair). Since 2019 when this article was posted and answered, the underlying Racket engine has changed to use Chez Scheme, and the performance ratios have also changed significantly.

Rerunning the above tests (I've included mutable vector operations as well, since the OP mentioned it):

```
#lang racket

(define (immut-hash [c (hash)] [r 10000000])
  (when (> r 0) (immut-hash (hash-set c (random #xffff) (random #xff)) (- r 1))))

(define (mut-hash [c (make-hash)] [r 10000000])
  (when (> r 0) (hash-set! c (random #xffff) (random #xff)) (mut-hash c (- r 1))))

(define (mut-vec [c (make-vector 65536)] [r 10000000])
  (when (> r 0) (vector-set! c (random #xffff) (random #xff)) (mut-vec c (- r 1))))

(time (immut-hash (hash)))
(time (immut-hash (hasheq)))
(time (mut-hash (make-hash)))
(time (mut-hash (make-hasheq)))
(time (mut-vec))
```

produces the following results:

```
cpu time: 4024 real time: 4409 gc time: 198
cpu time: 3991 real time: 4334 gc time: 188
cpu time: 2532 real time: 2631 gc time: 17
cpu time: 2432 real time: 2524 gc time: 21
cpu time: 1985 real time: 2173 gc time: 11
```

Conclusions from the year 2021 (using Racket's new Chez Scheme 8.x engine):

- The performance degradation from using hash/make-hash instead of hasheq/make-hasheq has essentially been eliminated.
- The performance degradation from using immutable hashes instead of mutable hashes has gone from over 4x to less than 2x.
- The worst case scenario (immutable hash) is now only 2x worse than the best case scenario (mutable vectors).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the keys of your hash will be fixnums, you could use `hasheq` (or `make-hasheq`) instead of `hash` (or `make-hash`). This gives a better performance, at least for Racket 7.4 3m variant on my Macbook Pro.

```
#lang racket

(define (immut-hash [c (hash)] [r 10000000])
  (when (> r 0) (immut-hash (hash-set c (random #xffff) (random #xff)) (- r 1))))

(define (mut-hash [c (make-hash)] [r 10000000])
  (when (> r 0) (hash-set! c (random #xffff) (random #xff)) (mut-hash c (- r 1))))

(time (immut-hash (hash)))
(time (immut-hash (hasheq)))
(time (mut-hash (make-hash)))
(time (mut-hash (make-hasheq)))
```

Here's the results:

```
cpu time: 9383 real time: 9447 gc time: 3181
cpu time: 6644 real time: 6658 gc time: 1105
cpu time: 2220 real time: 2225 gc time: 0
cpu time: 1647 real time: 1654 gc time: 0
```

There's a [recent thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-dev/9i0lTtvqwRI/Y4btuYELBQAJ) about performance of immutable hash. Jon compared the performance of immutable hash implemented by Patricia trie vs hash array mapped trie (HAMT), the hash type (`eq?` vs `equal?`), and the insertion order. You might want to take a look at the results.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. Yes, I tried hasheq as well and agree with your results. The other thread is also useful, but leads to the same conclusion, which is that the immutable versions are probably not going to be good enough. I'll keep working on it. For point of reference -- a C64 runs at around 1M cycles per second (slightly less for a PAL version, slightly more for a NTSC). That means I'd have roughly 10 seconds for 10M cycles, and above the best version of mutable is 6644 without doing anything else. Probably not enough headroom.  But, I'm enjoying the challenge.